# Automatically open a btn-group dropdown and select first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap3 drop down menu:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
     <span role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down bigger-130" style="color: gray;"></i>
     </span>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li>
               <a role="menuitem">
                  Mark done
               </a>
          </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

What I want to achieve is to automatically trigger the drop down and select the first item.
Here is the code I have so far (this code is part of an event handler):

```
    var menu = $(".dropdown-menu");
    menu.dropdown('toggle');
    menu.first().addClass("active");
    menu.first().focus();
```

This toggles and shows the drop down menu but does not set the first element to active, hitting tab navigates to something other than the menu items...

What is missing in my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`menu.first()` returns the `.dropdown-menu` element itself. You want to select its first child, i.e. the first `li`, so do:

```
menu.children().first().addClass('active')
```

Comment: +1. That worked, however the menu does not seem to trigger when I hit enter while it is active.

Comment: Do you want to trigger that menu item from code? You can call `.click()` on the element, i.e. `menu.children().first().click()` instead

Comment: What I actually want is to navigate through the menus and hit enter when I want to execute an action linked to one of these menus. Actually, even the navigation with the tab key is broken somehow (I can't move from one menu to the other) any idea?